# VSTS2010 Addin Development - Check-in hooks

Tags: visual-studio-addins, checkin

I've been tipping my toes in Visual Studio Add-In development. I've read some of the tutorials online, and studied some of the sample code provided.
Now I actually want to perform custom actions before/after a TFS check-in command is called by the user, but I can't seem to figure out where I can find a hook to start this.
Is there something like that available in the SDK? Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks a lot!
Roel

**Edit:**
The use of check-in policy is not gonna help me in my situation. I want to show dialogs before and/or after the check-in command is invoked. Even (if it is possible) to alter the existing check-in dialog.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link! Interesting read, but not exactly what I need. See edit for more info.